# Размытый текст TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, android-manifest

Не могу понять, почему текст в TextView такой нечеткий -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для примера тот же текст в другой программе (Pocket) -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/contentTextView"
android:text="Content:"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="14sp"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Пробовал менять цвет фона, размер шрифта, `android:typeface и android:textStyle` - ничего не помогает.

Comment: Мне кажется, что шрифты разные на скринах... А вообще скрины с одного девайса сделаны?

Comment: Да, с одного девайса. Шрифты разные, но я пробовал установить sans, monospace и serif - все становятся размытыми. Я думаю, дело в LinearLayout, нужно какую-то настройку поменять.

Comment: Решил проблему. Оказалось, нужно просто добавить `<uses-sdk>`.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно комменту ТС-а

> [нужно просто добавить `<uses-sdk>`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/362726/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-textview?rq=1#comment363890_362726)

Проблема, в данном, случае, была в отсутствии соответствующего тега в манифесте приложения.